# JavaScript how to remove the day name from date formate?

Tags: javascript, date, format

For a specific application, I need to convert my date format from

> Fri Mar 26 2021 16:00:01 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)

to

> January 01, 2023 00:00:00 GMT+03:00

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the format problem:

```
//1. Get closing time from event
time = new Date(item.returnValues['closingTime'] * 1000);
                    
//2. Formatting the date for the date counter input
const options = {  year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
firstPart= time.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
                   
//3. Get original GMT time from the var time
secondPart = time.toString().slice(15, 24); 
secondPart = secondPart.concat(" GMT+04:00 ");
                    
//4. concat the two strings into the desired form
ct = firstPart.concat(secondPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [mozila's documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString), when the time wants to display as a string, The first three letters always stand for weekday name and they will be separate from the other data with a single space, so we can omit 4 first characters (3 first letters + followed space) from the final string with a function like this :

```
let sampleDate = Date();

function sliceDayFromTime(dateTime) {
   return dateTime.slice(4);
}

console.log(sliceDayFromTime(sampleDate));
```

In order to use more advanced formatting, you can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) which is an object that enables language-sensitive date and time formatting.

For the specific example that you mentioned above, I believe that the code below is useful

```
var sampleDate = new Date();

var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
  hour12: false,
  timeZoneName: 'short'
});

function minimalFormatDate(date) {
    return formatter.format(date);
}

function advancedFromatDate(date) {
    return formatter.formatToParts(date).map(({type, value}, index) => {
        if (type === 'literal' && index === 5) {
            return ' '
        }
        return value;
    }).join('');
}

console.log('minimal formating example: ', minimalFormatDate(sampleDate));
console.log('advanced formating example: ', advancedFromatDate(sampleDate));
```